# Resources on the newest Java sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting

Where can I find<sup>1</sup> information resources, and probably, the source code for that new adaptive mergesort based sort algorithm mentioned by Joshua Bloch on his Devvox 2008 interview, and is mentioned as a [RFE report too](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6804124)?

<sup>1</sup> Remark: I used my favorite search engine, and its largest competitor too, without satisfactory result other than the RFE report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for 'timsort java' gave me this - the [OpenJDK7 patch](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/timsort.patch) which looks likes it's Joshua Bloch's implementation.

EDIT: Tim (unrelated, I guess!) has very kindly determined the URL for the actual [Timsort.java](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) from this repository.

Comment: Yes, I would need an undiff for that somehow.

Comment: I'm too lazy to do that, and OpenJDK does not seem work on my Windows PC. I'd rather have the source in one piece.

Comment: That's available from the same address minus the timsort.patch, isnt it? http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/

Comment: @Tim - thanks for that. I've amended the answer appropriately

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, there has been some discussion on the relevant OpenJDK mailing list.